# What's the difference between cpupower and cpuspeed?

Tags: performance, cpu-frequency

These two programs seems both doing freq scaling.

What's their difference?

Comment: have you looked at the man pages?

Comment: [CPUSpeed](https://carlthompson.net/Software/CPUSpeed) is old, version 1.5 was released in 2008. Supported CPUs are AMD Athlon XP-M, Pentium 4M, Transmeta Crusoe and the like. I don't think it's commonly used any more.